# How to convert from vertical menu to horizontal menu with submenus?

Tags: html, css

I want to convert vertical menu to horizontal menu. Previously it was working fine, but after adding the HTML code to customize it, the whole menu shows vertical.

Here is the css code:

```
.menuwidth {
  width:950px;
  background:#004489;
}
.navirow {
  border-top:1px solid #4c4c4c;
  box-shadow:0 4px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
  width:950px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:38px;
}
.navirow li a {
  border-radius:2px;
  -moz-border-radius:2px;
  -webkit-border-radius:2px;
}
.navirow li.home a {
  background-color:#1e3b66;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.navirow li home li a {
  background-color:transparent;
}
.navirow li.active a {
  font-weight:700;
  color:#eaeaea;
  background-color:#1e1e1e;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:none;
}
.navirow li.active li a {
  font-weight:500;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

And here is the html code:

```
<div class='menuwidth'>
<div class='navirow'>
<ul class='sf-menu'>
<li class='active home'> 
<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>Home</a>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Movies</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Cat 1</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>cat 2</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Cat 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Computer</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Software</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Mobile</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>Others</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Media</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>People</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Politics</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Society</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Travel</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Health</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Float left the li and it will convert them horizontal and the submenu , leave them without float.

```
ul li{
     floa:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working, but realized that in css ul were missing in my code. I might be missing some more codes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k412wtsq/10/). I've set-up the basic layout for the horizontal navigation menu and you can style it according to your needs. These are the new styles which I've used:

```
ul.sf-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.sf-menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

ul.sf-menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the response. I'm new with css and html, so still it will take time to stick in my head. BDW, actually I missed to provide sf-menu css code because i did not know it is related to the menu. If you wanna help i can provide it :-)

Comment: Sure, please update the code in your main question so that I can check it.

Comment: I have tried it on your link. It's showing fine in preview, but no any idea what's wrong with the template which i'm trying to modify.

Comment: So here is a bit of good news, i have pasted the exact HTML code you provided in JSFiddle, and it seems to work now. I don't know how to give thanks for this. Probably, after removing menuwidth and one </ul> at the end.